# After Palpatine killed Windu, why didn't Anakin try to arrest him instead of becoming his apprentice?

Tags: star-wars

After Palpatine killed Windu, Anakin had a shock on his own action. He even reflected:

> What have I done?

But, then, Palpatine asked him to become his apprentice to learn the ways of the dark side.

Why did Anakin agree to this? Earlier, he wanted Windu to arrest Palpatine. Why didn't he try to arrest Palpatine himself?

Comment: I'm  wondering if you missed the part where Anakin actively **helped the Chancellor to kill Mace Windu**.

Comment: After actively assisting in the death of a council member, he would have probably been expelled from the order, if said order managed to persist thru the temple raid when Anakin didn't help. Palpatine offered him a way out.

Answer (score 2):

He'd gone too far at that point, even if he did have a moment of clarity, he'd done too much to turn back. He (in the comics) has couple moments of clarity, being pulled back to the light side, only to reject it again, knowing that what he has done cannot be undone and he stays his path in the dark.

Comment: This is the right answer. Vader never fully succumbed to the Dark Side, but remained tempted and tormented by his choices and the pull to the light. Luke sensed this and used it to help his father come back.